# Is it possible to get notified when a new table trigger is added in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

For example, when tables are modified we get notified through the DDL triggers. However, these triggers are not invoked when a trigger is added for a table.

Is there another kind of a trigger for that? Or some other way we can be notified if that?

I can, of course, take a snapshot of the `sys.triggers` view with `parent_class = 1` before and after the SQL code is applied and compare, but I am curious if there is a better way.

**EDIT 1**

I wonder what is the meaning of the `CREATE_TRIGGER` value in the `sys.trigger_event_types` view...

Comment: I am curious how often you have triggers being created in your system. Honestly, aside from auditing triggers really should not be used very often. For the question at hand I don't know of a way to track new triggers being created.

Comment: You are spot on. These are indeed auditing triggers.

Comment: shouldn't knowing what's been modified be a part of your development design, review and source control process? Since such a thing is basically a code change, it should be visible through a traceable process which led to its implementation, surely.

Comment: I am a bit confused then. Since your triggers are used for auditing that means you had to create them and would know when it is added right? Or is there other process you are trying to automate or something when a trigger is added and you are trying to avoid having to do something in those situations?

Comment: What events do your DDL trigger(s) fire on? Trigger events are separate from Table events; see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542(v=sql.105).aspx & DDL Event Groups link on that page.

Comment: We have some code requirements for the triggers added to the system. Unfortunately, code reviews and best practices may not be enough when there are hundreds of developers. We want to help us on the Gated Check-In side and for that would like to know when a trigger is added.